# AttributeError: 'child' object has no attribute '_name'

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm a beginner to Python and trying to understand class inheritance. But when i try the following code i get this error :

```
AttributeError: 'child' object has no attribute '_name'
```

And here's the code :

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = "Smith"

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

class child(parent):
    def __init__(self, childname):
        self._childname = childname

    def getname(self):
        return "child : {} .. parent : {}".format(self._childname, super().name)

def main():
    Dad = parent()
    Son = child("jack")
    print(Son.getname())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Why is that ? Am i understanding class inheritance in Python correctly ?

Comment: How about `__name__` instead of `_name`?

Comment: Names of the form `__xxx__` are reserved for use by Python itself.

Comment: Are you actually trying to write code that runs in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x? If not, which one do you want an answer for? (It makes a difference in this case.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem actually occurs here:

```
def getname(self):
    return "child : {} .. parent : {}".format(self._childname, super().name)
```

To be more precise, `super().name` is the culprit: not only `super()` is useless and you shall have called `name()` instead of `name`, but if you look at the code of `name()`, you will notice that it uses the variable `_name`.

However, `_name` is initialized in the parent's `__init__` method. If you want it to be called, you should always call the parent `__init__` method in the child's one, it is not done automagically. Your child `__init__` method should be:

```
class child(parent):
    def __init__(self, childname):
        super().__init__()
        self._childname = childname
```

Comment: I would add "If you want the parent's `__init__` to be called" before "You should always…"  It may not necessarily be the case you wish this to happen, though the asker does.

Comment: How about passing an instance of the parent class in the child class constructor and use it everywhere instead of `super()`. What do you think is more efficient ?

Comment: @RafaelAdel I don't think so. Actually, you don't always have to call `super()`. For example, you used `super().name()` but `name()` was sufficient since you don't overrice the function `name` in `child`.

Comment: FYI, that syntax for super() will not work in Python 2.7.  You must include the name of the child object. e.g. super(child, self).__init__() or use Seth's answer below.

Comment: @Phil Well, I assumed it would work for him since the OP already uses it in his example.

Comment: The OP tagged his question both 2.7 and 3.x, and from a quick glance, the rest of his code will work in either (although it will create classic classes in 2.7, of course), so… it's kind of hard to guess which one he needs.

Comment: @RafaelAdel: That's a very bad idea. You're mixing up inheritance and encapsulation. Think of a human with kids. You _are_ both a child, and a parent. You also _have_ a parent (ideally, two). But that parent isn't you, and its (given) name isn't your name.

Comment: @abarnert So, you're talking about inheriting `child` from `parent` or passing instance of `parent` as a parameter into `child`'s constructor ?

Comment: @RafaelAdel: Yes, I'm saying that, while passing an instance of `parent` as a parameter into `child`'s constructor might be a reasonable thing to do for some _other_ reason, it isn't a reasonable way to solve this problem.